# Redirect with .htaccess URLs matching a prefix to a subfolder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdirectory

In a multilingual website I am trying to set a rule in .htaccess, so that the URLs that are contained in a folder, and that are matching a prefix, are redirected into a sub-folder.

In concrete:

`www.example.com/es/urlprefix*` ==> `www.example.com/es/subfolder/urlprefix*`

Example:

```
www.example.com/es/urlprefix_example
```

is redirected to

```
www.example.com/es/subfolder/urlprefix_example
```

I would also like to know how to do the reverse, that is:

`www.example.com/es/subfolder/urlprefix*` ==> `www.example.com/es/urlprefix*`

Comment: Do you want URL in browser to change or not?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following at the top of your `.htaccess` file to redirect to the subfolder:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteRule ^(es)/(urlprefix.*) /$1/subfolder/$2 [R,L]
```

To redirect the other way (to *remove* the subfolder) you could do something like this:

```
RewriteRule ^(es)/subfolder/(urlprefix.*) /$1/$2 [R,L]
```

Obviously you can't do both at the same time, without some additional *conditions*, otherwise you'll get a redirect loop.